# iOS & Android: Quickest way to get rid of Admob Banner ad without updating the whole app?

Tags: android, ios, admob

Is there a way to get rid of Admob Banner ads in iOS as well as Android without having to update the whole app? Just delete the ads from my AdMob backend maybe?

I only have a couple of hours left until launch, that is why updating is not really an option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can archive the ad units in the AdMob console, but that leaves the GADBannerViews and AdViews in the layouts/storyboards for your app. They won't receive and show ads, but they may still take up space.

Comment: @RedBrogdon thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that.

**But**, you can integrate [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) on both platforms (iOS & Android) and define a boolean parameter to set AdMob on/off.
Then you can change it from Firebase console easily without deploying another version.
You can also use segments for that attribute. For example, you can enable AdMob only on Android and disable on iOS.

So basically you still have to update the code for at least on time in order to enable remote config feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sounds good, will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed Alon points.The solution might be, get the Boolean variable from the server and show the adds based on that.For this you should do, server side as well as iOS and android code changes too.